# Social login in laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am new to Laravel. I need to login using Facebook, gmail and twitter. I also want to save the user profile, id, name and other basic information from the social profile. I know in Laravel we can use socialite.

Answer (score 1):

Use laravel 5.1 [socialite](https://github.com/laravel/socialite) package, you can get detail documentation about if from laravel official site [click here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#social-authentication) to view. With this you can get step by step tutorial from [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20151225200542/http://www.codeanchor.net/blog/complete-laravel-socialite-tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

Hybridauth plugin can use for mutiple social networking API in laravel

Currently hybrid auth available for Laravel 4.1

http://blog.elliothesp.co.uk/coding/laravel-4-and-hybrid-auth/

We can reuse for new laravel

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/adding-social-login-using-hybrid-auth-laravel5

Comment: i am using laravel 5.1.can you post how to do using socialite